# Restart List Numbering with C# Word Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I have a Word 2010 template with some bookmarks and styles that I must use to generate a Word document, after getting the information from some XMLs, and I'm using c# with the Interop (version 8.3). The template was given to me and I can't change it at all, as it follows the documentation rules of the company.

Sometimes, when I use the custom Numbered List style of the template, the numbering screws up, inexplicably starting at 2 instead of 1. Other times, it follows the numbering of the previous list, when I don't always want that to happen.

Fixing those cases would be easy if I could modify the existing styles from the template, or applying custom styles with `ContinuePreviousList: false` from my program, but the generated Word document **must** have the styles they force me to use.

If I open the Word document, right click over the list and choose **"Restart at 1"** option (*I don't have Word in English, hope that's the proper translation*), it fixes most of the problems that I might have, but I don't know how to use that from Interop. I have recorded macros and then translated to c# to know how Word makes some functions, but the mouse is locked when I start recording macros. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mouse is locked, but you can use the [right click mouse button](http://www.stetsenko.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/right_click_keyboard_key.jpg) on the keyboard to get the context menu, and then select Restart at 1 while recording your Macro.

I ended up with this using C# interop:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using MSWord = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ResetNumberingInWordDoc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var application = new MSWord.Application();
            var document = application.Documents.Open(@"C:\mydocument.docx");

            const int listNumber = 1; //The first list on the page is list 1, the second is list 2 etc etc

            document.Range().ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel(
                ListTemplate: document.ListTemplates[listNumber], 
                ContinuePreviousList: false, 
                ApplyTo: MSWord.WdListApplyTo.wdListApplyToWholeList,
                DefaultListBehavior: MSWord.WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior);

            document.Save();
            document.Close();

            application.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that I don't have the `ApplyListTemplateWithLevel` method in my ListFormat, maybe because my interop version is too old, but your code is what I see when recording a macro with "right click mouse button", so thank you!

Comment: Another method that seems to work for me, once you have located the paragraph with the numbered list format, is applying the "List_Norm" style to the numbers of the list (not the list content). This is my first post so I don't know how to proceed, should I answer my own question with another solution even if I already accepted yours?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the exact way of performing the **"Restart at 1"** function looking at a recorded macro. Once you have located the paragraph with the numbered list style, you have to select the number that you want to "restart at 1" and apply the "List_Norm" style:

```
listParagraph.SelectNumber(); //Select numbers from the NumberList paragraph
application.Selection.set_Style(document.Styles["List_Norm"]); //Apply "List_Norm" style
```

That way, the content of the list will keep the original style(s), but the list will start from 1.

The same code can be applied to restart the Title styles, but applying the "Tit_List" style instead of "List_Norm".